# How to achieve equal height cross browser divs

Tags: html

I am trying to get all divs within a container to have the same height as the biggest. Basically so that all divs are 100% height within the container and without fixing the height of any of the divs.

Below is what I've managed to come up with, but I cant seem to get it to work on all browsers. Is there a way to achieve this result but without using jquery, javascript.

The below results is by setting a container height but I want to achieve this with no fixed height as the content will change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 2</title>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width: 500px; background-color: fuchsia; height: 400px; display: table">
    <div style="display: table-row; height: 100%">
        <div style="width: 50%; background-color: blue; float: left; height: 100%; display: table-cell">col 1</div>
        <div style="width: 50%; background-color: green; float: left; height: 100%; display: table-cell">col 2<br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row; height: 100%">
        <div style="width: 30%; background-color: blue; float: left; height: 100%; display: table-cell">col 1</div>
        <div style="width: 30%; background-color: green; float: left; height: 100%; display: table-cell">col 2<br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please avoid using inline styles. [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: It was just for the example.

Answer (score 0):

To get all divs to *appear* as if they had the same height, you can use pseudo-elements to put the respective backgrounds behind each one of the divs. 
These pseudo-elements will then take the height of the wrapper-div which in turn is determined by the height of the highest div.

See a full explanation of the technique at Tuts+: [Solving the Equal Height Column Conundrum](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-solving-the-equal-height-column-conundrum--cms-20403)

Comment: Is there no other way to achieve this without using the pseudo-element method.